Is there a way to resolve a GitHub octokit.js library issue while trying to build the react app?
So I am using React for an application that makes calls to GitHub RESTapi using their octokit sdk.When I run the application using npm start, the application runs perfectly. Only when I use the command npm run build, I get an error related to octokit library.
C:\Users\Vaibhav\Desktop\devops-d2r> npm run build

> devops-d2r@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...

Failed to compile.

TypeError: C:\Users\Vaibhav\Desktop\devops-d2r\node_modules\@octokit\core\dist-web\index.js: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'body')

This is my package.json file
{
  "name": "devops-d2r",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "^7.20.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@octokit/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@octokit/rest": "^20.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "octokit": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}

and when i navigate to the directory path of the error and search for the 'body' variable, I do not find any...
// pkg/dist-src/index.js
import { getUserAgent } from "universal-user-agent";
import { Collection } from "before-after-hook";
import { request } from "@octokit/request";
import { graphql, withCustomRequest } from "@octokit/graphql";
import { createTokenAuth } from "@octokit/auth-token";

// pkg/dist-src/version.js
var VERSION = "5.2.0";

// pkg/dist-src/index.js
var noop = () => {
};
var consoleWarn = console.warn.bind(console);
var consoleError = console.error.bind(console);
var userAgentTrail = `octokit-core.js/${VERSION} ${getUserAgent()}`;
var Octokit = class {
  static {
    this.VERSION = VERSION;
  }
  static defaults(defaults) {
    const OctokitWithDefaults = class extends this {
      constructor(...args) {
        const options = args[0] || {};
        if (typeof defaults === "function") {
          super(defaults(options));
          return;
        }
        super(
          Object.assign(
            {},
            defaults,
            options,
            options.userAgent && defaults.userAgent ? {
              userAgent: `${options.userAgent} ${defaults.userAgent}`
            } : null
          )
        );
      }
    };
    return OctokitWithDefaults;
  }
  static {
    this.plugins = [];
  }
  /**
   * Attach a plugin (or many) to your Octokit instance.
   *
   * @example
   * const API = Octokit.plugin(plugin1, plugin2, plugin3, ...)
   */
  static plugin(...newPlugins) {
    const currentPlugins = this.plugins;
    const NewOctokit = class extends this {
      static {
        this.plugins = currentPlugins.concat(
          newPlugins.filter((plugin) => !currentPlugins.includes(plugin))
        );
      }
    };
    return NewOctokit;
  }
  constructor(options = {}) {
    const hook = new Collection();
    const requestDefaults = {
      baseUrl: request.endpoint.DEFAULTS.baseUrl,
      headers: {},
      request: Object.assign({}, options.request, {
        // @ts-ignore internal usage only, no need to type
        hook: hook.bind(null, "request")
      }),
      mediaType: {
        previews: [],
        format: ""
      }
    };
    requestDefaults.headers["user-agent"] = options.userAgent ? `${options.userAgent} ${userAgentTrail}` : userAgentTrail;
    if (options.baseUrl) {
      requestDefaults.baseUrl = options.baseUrl;
    }
    if (options.previews) {
      requestDefaults.mediaType.previews = options.previews;
    }
    if (options.timeZone) {
      requestDefaults.headers["time-zone"] = options.timeZone;
    }
    this.request = request.defaults(requestDefaults);
    this.graphql = withCustomRequest(this.request).defaults(requestDefaults);
    this.log = Object.assign(
      {
        debug: noop,
        info: noop,
        warn: consoleWarn,
        error: consoleError
      },
      options.log
    );
    this.hook = hook;
    if (!options.authStrategy) {
      if (!options.auth) {
        this.auth = async () => ({
          type: "unauthenticated"
        });
      } else {
        const auth = createTokenAuth(options.auth);
        hook.wrap("request", auth.hook);
        this.auth = auth;
      }
    } else {
      const { authStrategy, ...otherOptions } = options;
      const auth = authStrategy(
        Object.assign(
          {
            request: this.request,
            log: this.log,
            // we pass the current octokit instance as well as its constructor options
            // to allow for authentication strategies that return a new octokit instance
            // that shares the same internal state as the current one. The original
            // requirement for this was the "event-octokit" authentication strategy
            // of https://github.com/probot/octokit-auth-probot.
            octokit: this,
            octokitOptions: otherOptions
          },
          options.auth
        )
      );
      hook.wrap("request", auth.hook);
      this.auth = auth;
    }
    const classConstructor = this.constructor;
    for (let i = 0; i < classConstructor.plugins.length; ++i) {
      Object.assign(this, classConstructor.plugins[i](this, options));
    }
  }
};
export {
  Octokit
};

The build folder gets created, except for the index.html

What really is the issue and how can I resolve this?

I solved this problem by migrating to vite, instead of using create-react-app.
CRA is deprecated, hence it is safer to use vite. Do let me know if there is any other reason that could be causing this error!!
